# Further using the .split() function based on conditions?

Tags: python, list, split

How would you be able to use the .split() function based on conditions?

Lets say I have the raw data:

```
Apples,Oranges,Strawberries Green beans,Yellow green Beans,Tomatoes,Broccoli
```

My intended result is:

```
['Apples','Oranges','Strawberries','Green beans','Yellow green Beans','Tomatoes','Brocolli']
```

*Note, that `'Strawberries'` and `'Green beans'` are splitted.*

What would be the best way of approaching this to split it into the intended way?

Comment: Why don't you split 'Green' and 'beans'? What is the rule that you want to apply?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma between `Strawberries` and `Green beans`? And is the "raw data" there supposed to be a string? You didn't put quotes on it, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: If the missing comma is something you need to be able to deal with, this may require nontrivial natural language processing. If so, you will need to accept that there will be errors.

Comment: *Why* do you need to deal with this? What context does this task appear in? Do you have a list of items that can appear in your input? Or is your program just supposed to somehow figure out what is or isn't a food?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?  I'm taking advantage of the fact that your foods are plural:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

def splitter(string, use_s_trick=False):
    plant_foods_list = string.split(',')
    for plant_food in plant_foods_list:
        if use_s_trick:
            words = plant_food.split(' ')
            words_list = []
            for word in words:
                words_list.append(word)
                if word.endswith('s'):
                    yield ' '.join(words_list)
                    words_list = []
        else:
            yield plant_food

plant_foods_str = 'Apples,Oranges,Strawberries Green beans,Yellow green Beans,Tomatoes,Broccoli'
for plant_food in splitter(plant_foods_str, use_s_trick=True):
    print(plant_food)
```

Comment: `#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python`? Really? Well, I personally try to keep my scripts as portable as possible...

Comment: It's easy to change, and it shows what version of Python I tested with.  Also, it shows up in top well.